# Make like HTC popup

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I had a HTC phone. And I see this pop up. It 's pretty cool, especial in its animation. Does any boy tell me what does it call(I call it HTC popup) and how to do that. Do we have a framework to do this?

Thanks in advance, (1 rep per answer :D)
[image]

click [here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-tNS3yMfwDBY/UFITF_qU1bI/AAAAAAAAFgg/VK5Rbf-nuHo/s480/popup.png) if the image doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that need use QuickAction. [QuickAction](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/)